# Allowing cross-domain access of third-party WMS server from OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I have a web site with an [OpenLayers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLayers) client. I also have a [GeoServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoServer) running on the same domain. My OpenLayers uses services like [WMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service), [GML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language), etc. from this GeoServer installation and everything runs fine.

Now, I want to add another WMS layer to my existing set of layers. This layer is provided by a third-party WMS (not owned by me). How can I add this layer to my OpenLayers by bypassing the cross-domain issue.

PS: I am aware that GeoServer allows adding third-party WMS as a new data store and lets me publish the available layers, but I am facing some projection issues there which I will be asking in a different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need a proxy if you are looking to do WFS or WMS GetFeatureInfo requests. Basic WMS requests should work out of the box in OpenLayers (or any other client).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about GeoServer, but in OpenLayers you can use 3rd party WMS directly. All you need is set up [ProxyHost](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost).